# python script and libGLEW related error (menpo.io API)

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, glew, menpo

I am writing a python script in Ubuntu 14.04 that imports the menpo.io (API for deformable models) that results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Dropbox/pyFaceDepression/AAM_Menpo_final.py", line 1, in <module>
    import menpo.io as mio
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import io
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/io/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from base import (import_auto, import_image, import_images,
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/io/base.py", line 815, in <module>
    from menpo.io.extensions import (mesh_types, all_image_types,
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/io/extensions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from menpo.io.landmark import (LM3Importer, LANImporter, LM2Importer,
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/io/landmark.py", line 9, in <module>
    from menpo.shape import PointCloud
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/shape/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from menpo.shape.mesh import TriMesh, ColouredTriMesh, TexturedTriMesh
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/shape/mesh/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .coloured import ColouredTriMesh
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/shape/mesh/coloured.py", line 3, in <module>
    from menpo.rasterize import Rasterizable
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/rasterize/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from menpo.rasterize.opengl import GLRasterizer
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menpo/rasterize/opengl.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cyrasterize.base import CyRasterizerBase
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cyrasterize/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cyrasterize.base import CyRasterizer
  File "/home/miniconda/envs/menpo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cyrasterize/base.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cyrasterize.glrasterizer import GLRasterizer
ImportError: libGLEW.so.@glew_version@: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The library I import is called Menpo.io

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to apologise, this is actually totally my fault as I was trying to update some of our build scripts and accidentally released a broken build of GLEW. To fix this, you can run:

`conda install -c menpo --force glew=1.10.0`

Which should download and reinstall GLEW and hopefully fix this problem.

Please reply back if you have any problems at all!

Comment: Thanks it worked and it printed the following messages The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    glew-1.10.0                |                0         372 KB

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    glew: 1.11.0-0 --> 1.10.0-0                                                                                                                                             Please though !!! Fix the online versions since people depend on your library !!!! It is really useful !

Comment: Glad it worked, I have fixed it. Anyone who follows the instructions as you did will get a working version again :) that was a temporary problem created over the weekend!